# java...based on Collections

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

class Employee1 implements Comparable<Employee1> {
    int empno;

    String name;
    Employee1(int i,String j) {
        empno=i;
        name=j;
    }

    public int compareTo(Employee1 e1) {
        Employee1 e2=this;
        Integer i1=e1.empno;
        Integer i2=e2.empno;
        return i1.compareTo(i2);
    }
}

public class Employee {
    public static void display(ArrayList<Employee1> i) {
        for(Employee1 o:i){
            System.out.println(o.empno);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Employee1> ob=new ArrayList<Employee1>();
        Employee1 e1=new Employee1(1001,"A");
        Employee1 e2=new Employee1(1002,"B");
        ob.add(e2);
        ob.add(e1);
        Collections.sort(ob);
        display(ob);
    }
}
```

The output should be `1001 1002` but instead the output is `1002 1001`.

First I passed the `e2` object with `empno` to the List and then 
`e1` with `empno` of 1001

Due to the `compareTo` method in `Employee1` - `e1.compareTo(e2);` should be the same as `1001.compareTo(1002);` So why are they showing in the wrong order?

Comment: ok..Andremoniy ...thats fine...Will u please tell me the flow of .....

Comment: why do you use that many dots? its hard to connect the dots that way :)

Comment: flow of the statement ....return i1.compareTo(i2); with the objects ..e1 and e2..??

Comment: ok..just i need the flow of the statement..  return i1.compareTo(i2)..with the objects e1=1001 and e2=1002

Comment: It seems, that @vinodh uses `.` as `space`. May be he has troubles with keyboard? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
  return i1.compareTo(i2);
```

to

```
  return -i1.compareTo(i2);
```

or

```
  return i2.compareTo(i1);
```

Comment: yes i got that...if it is still.. return i1.compareTo(i1)..then after passing the objects ..it becomes 1001.compareTo(1002);  right?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is just badly written.

Here's how the method should be coded:

```
public int compareTo(Employee1 other) {
    return this.empno.compareTo(other.empno);
}
```